# LLVM IR -> WebAssembly. Wasm empty module | instance

Tags: llvm, webassembly

I'm trying to generate valid wasm file that'll be understood by WebBrowser (Firefox) correctly, but I'm not sure that I'm doing wrong here

Here's `Main.ll` file

```
define i32 @main() {
  ret i32 42
}
```

Then I'm using llc (Linux):

> ./llc -mtriple=wasm32-unknown-unknown -O3 -filetype=obj main.ll -o main.o

Then I'm using wasm-ld (Linux):

> ./wasm-ld main.o -o main.wasm --no-entry -allow-undefined

Then I'm copying `main.wasm` to Windows and then opening this local file page:

```
|-- fille.html
|-- main.wasm
```

---

```
<div id="test">
</div>

<style>
    #test
    {
        border: 3px solid red;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<script>
    fetch("main.wasm")
        .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
        .then(bytes => WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, {}))
        .then(results => {
          window.alert(results.instance.exports.main());
        });
</script>
```

But

> TypeError: results.instance.exports.main is not a function

What's wrong?

Here's result of:

> console.log(JSON.stringify(results));

```
{"module":{},"instance":{}}
```

Versions:

> ./llc --version

```
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
LLVM version 10.0.0
```

> ./wasm-ld --version

```
LLD 10.0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you haven't exported any symbols during linking.

You might want to check [`the Exports section of wasm-ld docs`](https://lld.llvm.org/WebAssembly.html#exports) for details, but here's what they say about defaults:

> When building an executable, only the entry point (`_start`) and symbols with the `WASM_SYMBOL_EXPORTED` flag are exported by default.

You have couple of options:

1. Rename `main` to `_start` - this will ensure that `_start` is exported and any of its dependencies are correctly imported from the environment, rather than GCd altogether, like what happens right now.
2. Call `wasm-ld` with `--export-all` flag - this will export all symbols in the object file. This option is generally not recommended, since you might be preventing useful size optimisations and exposing things you didn't mean to expose, but might be fine for prototyping.
3. Call `wasm-ld` with `--export-dynamic` - this will export all symbols that are marked as visible at the IR level.
4. Explicitly list symbols when calling `wasm-ld` with e.g. `--export=main`.

One more caveat to be aware of in all options except (1) is that `main` is treated in a special way and with your current code it will result in two different symbols:

1. `main` - an auto-generated function wrapper with two args for `argc` and `argv` that calls your function.
2. `__original_main` - a symbol for the function that you actually defined.

To make sure you don't run into this, either follow option 1 and rename `main` to `_start` which is a Wasm-specific entry point and doesn't accept any parameters, or change signature of your `main` function to the correct one and accept both `argc` and `argv` like in C.

Hopefully this all should get you going.